# php data from database not displaying

Tags: php, oracle, fetch

I tried to count a record from database, but when echoing the value wasn't display.  the SQL itself have no error. tested

tried oci_fetch_array, oci_fetch_object...same..output not displayed

```
$q="SELECT COUNT(NOKP) as BIL 
        FROM IRAISE_MOHON 
        WHERE NOKP='".$staf['nokp'][$i]."' 
        ";
    echo $q."<br>";



    $sq=OCIParse($conn,$q);
    $rs=OCIExecute($sq);
    //$x=oci_fetch_all($sq);
    $x = oci_fetch_assoc($sq);

    echo ($i+1).'Data: ' . $x["BIL"] .'<br>';
```

$x["BIL"] should return a value 0 and above

Comment: What produce var_dump($x);

Comment: Could you please try the following `echo ($i+1).'Data: ' . ($x["BIL"]==0? "0": $x["BIL"] ) .'<br>';` just to avoid the expression being treated as a false; `var_dump($x);` will help further, please also mention the php version & OS which you are using. Thanks.

Comment: var_dump($x) produce result bool(false)...

Comment: currently using PHP Version 5.6.30 on Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)

Comment: still cannot resolve this problem..any helps is really appreciated..

Comment: Problem solved!...